# How to find differences of mat files in Python in human readable format?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

`.mat` files can be loaded into Python with:

```
import scipy.io
matdata1 = scipy.io.loadmat('file1.mat')
matdata2 = scipy.io.loadmat('file2.mat')
```

the files can then be piped and save the mat files as text by calling the following Python function:

```
def mat2txt(matdata):
    for k, v in matdata.items():  #Python 3 specific
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            myprint(v)
        else:
            print (k,v)
```

The two `.mat` files that are being compared are of the same structure and type with different values.

I would like to able to identify the different values in human readable format, and not just their location.

I have tried:

```
diff matdata1.txt matdata2.txt 
diff matdata1.txt matdata2.txt | grep "<" | sed 's/^<//g' 
grep -v -F -x -f matdata1.txt matdata2.txt
```

which do not point to specific differences in values, and they are not within Python. I hoped to store the `.mat` files as `.txt` to be able to create a static state to compare the files data at different dates relative to itself and other files, as well as, affording the opportunity to store in `git` for future comparisons.

A toy example of the resulting data files are:

`matdata1.txt`

```
b [[([[(array([[0]], dtype=uint8),)]],)]]
a [[([[(array([[0]], dtype=uint8),)]],)]]
c [[ ([[(array([[ ([[122, 139, 156, 173, 190, 207, 224, 1, 18, 35, 52, 69, 86, 103, 120], [138, 155, 172, 189, 206, 223, 15, 17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102, 119, 121], [154, 171, 188, 205, 222, 14, 16, 33, 50, 67, 84, 101, 118, 135, 137], [170, 187, 204, 221, 13, 30, 32, 49, 66, 83, 100, 117, 134, 136, 153], [186, 203, 220, 12, 29, 31, 48, 65, 82, 99, 116, 133, 150, 152, 169], [202, 22, 11, 28, 45, 47, 64, 81, 98, 115, 132, 149, 151, 168, 185], [218, 10, 27, 33, 46, 63, 80, 97, 114, 131, 148, 165, 167, 184, 201], [9, 26, 43, 60, 62, 11, 96, 113, 130, 147, 164, 166, 183, 200, 217], [25, 42, 59, 61, 78, 95, 112, 99, 146, 163, 180, 182, 199, 216, 8], [41, 58, 75, 77, 94, 111, 128, 145, 162, 179, 181, 198, 215, 7, 24], [57, 74, 76, 93, 110, 127, 144, 161, 178, 195, 197, 214, 6, 23, 40], [73, 90, 92, 109, 126, 143, 160, 177, 194, 196, 213, 5, 22, 39, 56], [89, 91, 108, 125, 142, 159, 176, 193, 210, 212, 4, 21, 38, 55, 72], [105, 107, 124, 141, 158, 175, 192, 209, 211, 3, 20, 37, 54, 71, 88], [106, 123, 140, 157, 174, 191, 208, 225, 2, 19, 36, 53, 70, 87, 104]],)]], 
      dtype=[('c', 'O')]),)]],)]]
__header__ b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Mon Jun 27 20:55:29 2016'
d [[1]]
__globals__ []
f ['string']
__version__ 1.0
e [[2]]
```

`matdata2.txt`

```
e [[2]]
d [[1]]
__globals__ []
f ['string']
__header__ b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Mon Jun 27 20:54:48 2016'
c [[ ([[(array([[ ([[122, 139, 156, 173, 190, 207, 224, 1, 18, 35, 52, 69, 86, 103, 120], [138, 155, 172, 189, 206, 223, 15, 17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102, 119, 121], [154, 171, 188, 205, 222, 14, 16, 33, 50, 67, 84, 101, 118, 135, 137], [170, 187, 204, 221, 13, 30, 32, 49, 66, 83, 100, 117, 134, 136, 153], [186, 203, 220, 12, 29, 31, 48, 65, 82, 99, 116, 133, 150, 152, 169], [202, 219, 11, 28, 45, 47, 64, 81, 98, 115, 132, 149, 151, 168, 185], [218, 10, 27, 44, 46, 63, 80, 97, 114, 131, 148, 165, 167, 184, 201], [9, 26, 43, 60, 62, 79, 96, 113, 130, 147, 164, 166, 183, 200, 217], [25, 42, 59, 61, 78, 95, 112, 129, 146, 163, 180, 182, 199, 216, 8], [41, 58, 75, 77, 94, 111, 128, 145, 162, 179, 181, 198, 215, 7, 24], [57, 74, 76, 93, 110, 127, 144, 161, 178, 195, 197, 214, 6, 23, 40], [73, 90, 92, 109, 126, 143, 160, 177, 194, 196, 213, 5, 22, 39, 56], [89, 91, 108, 125, 142, 159, 176, 193, 210, 212, 4, 21, 38, 55, 72], [105, 107, 124, 141, 158, 175, 192, 209, 211, 3, 20, 37, 54, 71, 88], [106, 123, 140, 157, 174, 191, 208, 225, 2, 19, 36, 53, 70, 87, 104]],)]], 
      dtype=[('c', 'O')]),)]],)]]
a [[([[(array([[1]], dtype=uint8),)]],)]]
b [[([[(array([[0]], dtype=uint8),)]],)]]
__version__ 1.0
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample pair of `.mat` file contents? So that we can use it for testing?  In any case I believe you should look into the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html) module from the standard library, it can produce html files that highlight differences both between lines and inside the lines, and also provides an API to describe the differences between two files, so that you can do what you want with them.

Comment: It would be nice to have some idea of the structure and type of the data in the files.  Depending on what's saved in MATLAB that structure can be quite complex.  If the arrays (lowest level objects) are 2d, `np.savetxt` can produce a nice readable table of values.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for pointing that out.  unfortunately they are not 2d.  I will create a sample input file just now.

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you for pointing me to that library.  And thank you for requesting a sample pair of the files.  My intention of including the long line for variable ```c``` was to try to show the challenge of finding the values within an array that are different.